# Modifying cost per click of an Adword keyword by using API

Tags: php, api, google-ads-api

I need to update cost per click of keywords but I found information only about ads and campaigns.

```
$budgetService = $user->GetService('BudgetService', ADWORDS_VERSION);
$bm = new Money('10000000');
$campaign->budget->amount = $bm;
$boperation = new BudgetOperation();
$boperation->operand = $campaign->budget;
$boperation->operator = 'SET';
$budgetService->mutate($boperation);
```

But how to apply new value of CPC for a single keyword by it's id and campaign id? I can fetch all information about keywords but don't know how to update it. I use v201609 of adwords API.

Comment: Look for bids, you can't set the price, you can only make a bid. Keyword demand makes the price

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201609/BasicOperations/UpdateKeyword.php

Commit appeared within 12 hours after I asked a question and it contains example of updating keywords in v201609